# Django and jQuery/JSON - NmapService is not JSON serializable

Tags: jquery, python, json, django

I'd like to appologize for duplicates, I've been googling for the past hour and a half but no success.

**Scenario**
I have a web application that parses user submitted files.
I added a button for every host in the template that serves purpose to add the clicked host to the session. In later stages of the application, every host in the session get's added to the reportgenerator using ReportLab.

The functionality of what I currently have works fine, untill I click a host that holds an NmapService object.
Then I get this error

traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /addToSession/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stripped>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 235, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "<stripped>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 50, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "<stripped>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 82, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "<stripped>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 68, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "<stripped>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 88, in encode
    serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)
  File "<stripped>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 95, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: NmapService: [open 23/tcp telnet (product: Cisco IOS telnetd devicetype: switch ostype: IOS)] is not JSON serializable
[18/Dec/2015 14:18:51] "POST /addToSession/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17246
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def addToSession(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
           print("Request is ajax");
           try:
              hostID = request.POST.get('host')
              try:
                  parser = p(request.session['nmapLink'])
                  myList = request.session['hostsforReport']
                  var = parser.getHostById(hostID)
                  if var in myList:
                      myList.remove(var)
                      message = 'Host removed from session.'
                  else:
                      myList.append(parser.getHostById(hostID))
                      message = 'Host added to session.'
                  request.session['hostsforReport'] = myList
              except:
                  e = sys.exc_info()[0]
                  message = 'Something went wrong ' + str(e)
              message = 'Success'
          except:
              e = sys.exc_info()[0]
              message = 'Error: ' + str(e)
          data = { 'message' : message}
          for obj in request.session['hostsforReport']:
              print(obj)
          return JsonResponse(data)
      else:
          return render_to_response('index.html', locals())
  else:
      return render_to_response('index.html', locals())
```

template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container col-md-12">
    <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel panel-heading">
        <h1>Nmap scan results</h1>
    </div>
    {% for host in myList %}
    <div class="panel panel-body">
    <button class="btn btn-info add" host="{{host.id}}" onclick="addtoSession" >Add to session</button>
        <form class="form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2>Scan results for {{host.id }}</h2>

            <hr>
            <h3>Algemene informatie</h3>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            Host ipv4 : {{host.host_ipv4}}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            host ipv6 : {{host.host_ipv6}}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            host mac: {{host.host_mac}}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            Host last boot: {{host.host_boot}}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Host uptime: {{host.host_uptime}}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Host os: {{host.host_os}}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Correctness: {{host.host_guess_percentage_os}}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr>
            <h3>Discovered services</h3>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <th>Protocol</th>
                    <th>Port</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Service name</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for x in host.host_services %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{x.protocol}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.port}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.state}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.service}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr>
            {% if host.host_scripts %}
            <h3>Scripts</h3>
            <table class="table">
                {% for script in host.host_scripts %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="label label-warning">{{script.scriptName}}</span></td>
                        <td>{{script.scriptOutput}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <hr>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Get CSRF token
    function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < cookies.length ; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            //Is this the cookie we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length +1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length +1));
                break;
            }
    }
}
    return cookieValue;
}
$('.add').click(function addtoSession(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'addToSession' %}",
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken : getCookie('csrftoken'),
        "host" : $(this).attr("host"),
    },
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(json['message']);
    },
    error: function(rs,e) {
        alert(json['message']);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I would appriciate any help in solving this error. I can't seem to figure it out on my own.
What actions do I need to undertake to make the NmapService list serializable?
Any help is appriciated!

**Edit**
As Gocht pointed out, it's because host_scripts or host_services is not serializable.
Using google I came to the following solution:

```
host_services = []
if host.services:
for service in host.services:
        host_services.append(service)
        host_services = json.dumps(host_services, default=lambda o:o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
host_scripts = []
if host.scripts_results:
    for script in host.scripts_results:
        scripts = {}
        scripts['scriptName'] = script['id']
        scripts['scriptOutput'] = script['output']
        host_scripts.append(scripts)
    host_scripts = json.dumps(host_scripts, default=lambda o:o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Unfortunately this render's the entire functionality of the jQuery useless.
What else is there that I can do to achieve said scenario.

Comment: Some objects are not serializable, this is the case. Pick specific data from your object and serialize them instead of the whole object.

Comment: Is there some way I can write my own serializer? It's important I can get the data to the repor generator.